# Android Espresso how to test flow to specific activity from different paths

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am using espresso to test the contents of text view in an activity say C.
It is possible to reach this activity either via A or via B, each resulting in a different value of the text view.

By default, Espresso always runs the test A->C and never from B->C. 
How do I test both these flows, as Espresso only let's me specify the name of the activity containing the text view rather than the path taken to reach there.

I am using this to specify class C in my test :

```
 @Rule
        public ActivityTestRule<C> mActivityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
                C.class);
```

How do I test both the aforementioned flows ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can provide a different intent to the `ActivityRule` to simulate coming from B.

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<C> activityRule = new ActivityTestRule<>(
    C.class,
    true,    // initialTouchMode
    false);  // launchActivity: false to set intent
```

In your test, launch your activity with a specific intent:

```
@Test
public void fromB() {
  Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.putExtra("your_key", "your_value");  // Whatever B uses to launch C

  activityRule.launchActivity(intent);

  // Verify the text view.
}
```

More info: http://blog.sqisland.com/2015/04/espresso-21-activitytestrule.html

Comment: In the fromB() method, where do you specify that it is B that is launching C and not some other activity ? Also, wouldn't I need to open B first ?

Comment: How does B launch C? What is the intent it uses? Use the same intent in the fromB method.

Comment: I am using a simple Intent i = new Intent(B.this, C.class); followed by startActivity(i). How do I implement this in the test ?

Comment: Then how does C know to display something different on the text view? What is the logic?